Memory leak from different software
My system just start to get memory leak from VSCode (just while debugging RUST - just starting the debugging the session - editing is fine) and while loading Civilization VI. Last week, both were working. I've already updated the system (I'm at Ubuntu 22.04). The issue: when I start debugging or when I launch CivVI, the memory consumption start to grow and my system (with 16GB RAM) freezes in less than 30 seconds. If I quit the software, everything goes back to normal.
My guess is that some common library was updated and now is leaking the memory. But I have no clue of how to trace the origin. I tried the classical ps, but I just got the main process.
Does anyone can give me a direction in finding the source of the leak?
Thank you!

Consider reporting a bug at the github repos of these software

But the thing is that it should be something in my computer - everything was working until some days ago. It seems that, for some types of processes, the RAM is not free'd until the software is closed. If I just go to Steam or VSCode and say "memory leak", they will tell me "it works on 1.000.000.000 users, it's your computer".
